# Don't copy all rows in postgres

Tags: postgresql, copy

I want to copy some data from a table to another but I dont want to copy all the rows, just a few a them (like only the first 100).

I didn't find an option in the `COPY` command for this.
So that's only possible or not ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't look very hard.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

> To copy into a file just the countries whose names start with 'A':
>
> COPY (SELECT * FROM country WHERE country_name LIKE 'A%') TO
>   '/usr1/proj/bray/sql/a_list_countries.copy';

So you would want `COPY (SELECT ... LIMIT 100)`.

I'm assuming you want to copy between databases or via an intermediate file or something, otherwise you just want to use `INSERT ... SELECT` as shown in another answer.

Comment: but what if I want to copy from a file. COPY table_name FROM 'filename'. It does not seem to be possible to limit the number of rows to be copied. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
INSERT INTO table2(col_list) 
SELECT col_list FROM table1 WHERE condtitions ORDER BY order_col_list LIMIT X;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit number of rows when you copy `(SELECT ...LIMIT) to`, but not `COPY from`. You did not find such options in [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), because there are no such.

use `insert into ... select from ... limit 100` instead